# Linear Algebra Question Involving Steinitz's Exchange Argument to form A Basis of a Vector Space Disjoint From Some Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hello to prepare for my linear algebra final I was doing some end-of-chapter textbook problems and this one does not have a solution. I attempted a solution which I am unsure of, and I was wondering if the holes could be pointed out, or if there is a more sophisticated approach.

This is my first question on this discussion board-- I hope my question is appropriate

Question: Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) vector space let $U \subsetneq V$ be a (proper) subspace. Show that there exists a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ such that $U \cap \mathcal{B} = \emptyset$

My approach:
Let $S = \{s_1,s_2, \dots, s_m\}$, $m <n$ be a basis of $U$ which exists due to $U$ being finite dimensional. We can complete $S$ to a basis of $V$, $S' = \{s_1,\dots,s_m, s_{m+1},\dots,s_n\}$ by Steinitz's exchange argument

Clearly $\{s_j\} \cap U = \emptyset$ for $j = m+1,\dots,n$, otherwise $s_j \in U \equiv span\{s_1,\dots,s_m\}$, which would contradict $S'$ being a basis (the vectors aren't linearly independent).

Now consider $\mathcal{B} = \{s_1 + s_{m+1}, s_2 + s_{m+1}, \dots, s_m + s_{m+1}, s_{m+1}, \dots, s_n\}$ (this is the part I am unsure of)

These vectors are linearly independent, as if we try to form the 0 vector from them,
$$0 = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \lambda_ib_i\ \ \ \ (b_i \in \mathcal{B})$$
$$ = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m(\lambda_is_{m+1} + \lambda_is_i) + \sum\limits_{i = m+1}^n \lambda_is_i$$

Setting $\overline{\lambda} := \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m+1}\lambda_i$, we see then
$$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m(\lambda_is_i) + \overline{\lambda}s_{m+1} + \sum\limits_{i=m+2}^n\lambda_is_i$$
$$0=\sum\limits_{i=1, i\neq m+1}^n(\lambda_is_i) + \overline{\lambda}s_{m+1}$$
But since all these vectors are linearly independent (since they reside in $S'$ which was argued to be linearly independent), the only way this can occur is if $\overline{\lambda} = 0$ and $\lambda_i = 0$ for each $i$ not $m+1$, which implies that, since $\overline{\lambda} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m+1}\lambda_i$, that each $\lambda_i$ is actually 0.

Hence, $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent

Futhermore, $\{s_i + s_{m+1}\} \cap U = \emptyset$ for every $i$, as since $s_{m+1} \notin U$ and $U$ is a subspace, linear combinations involving $s_{m+1}$ don't reside in $U$.

Hence, $\mathcal{B} \cap U = \emptyset$ and forms a basis of $V$, as desired.

Comment: This is correct. Just a remark though: it would be cleaner to just write explicitely $\lambda_{m + 1} = \bar{\lambda} - \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i= 0$.

Comment: Another improvment (this one is much needed!). For $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$, $s_i  +  s_{m + 1} \notin U$ for otherwise $s_{m+1} = \underbrace{s_i  +  s_{m + 1}}_{\in U} - \underbrace{s_i}_{\in U} \in U$. It doesn't cost much time to write those arguments explicitely, don't you think?